# How to display google map in right half of the screen while left half of the screen contain list view

Tags: android, android-layout

i am working on a app, where i need to display the google map on the right half of the screen of my device. The left half of the screen contain text in list view format. Please help me how to design the UI part or layout.xml.....Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: use fragments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use linear layout with horizontal orientation and put both your mapview and listview inside it , now give similar weight to them .May be that will work .for example give layout_weight 1 or 0.5 in both mapview and listview .

Answer (score 0):

Try use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and here are some links to training

[Using Fragments in Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html%E2%80%8E)

[trading for fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look into something like this? I've used this format in apps before

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <MapView />

    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView />

 </LinearLayout>
```